# Krakend download for windows not available

Tags: windows, exe, krakend

Krakend on their official website don't have downloadable .exe file for windows platform.

Does only to work with krakend on the windows is using docker ?

[image: Official krakend download page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KrakenD does not provide native support for Windows as it is too much effort for a product that is server based. Still, you can use KrakenD on Windows using Docker.